# start an Activity from an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-intent, dialog

I want to start an activity from an AlertDialog.Builder But I can't s start any activity from OnclickListener of the dialog Interface. from both of the `setPositiveButton` and `setNegativeButton`(tried 2 ways to show as an example), both of them don't work and doesn't start either `menuactivity` or `exo5P1`.

```
public class exo5 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    private EditText edt1, edt2, edt3, edt4, edt5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exo4);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        edt1 = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        edt2 = findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        edt3 = findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        edt4 = findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        edt5 = findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder ValidationDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(exo5.this);
                ValidationDialog.setTitle("Validation");
                ValidationDialog.setMessage("Voulez-vous vraiment valider").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vous Avez bien validé votre choix", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent( exo5.this,exo5P1.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Non", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vous Avez annulé votre choix", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent =new Intent(exo5.this,menuActivity.class);
                        exo5.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                 AlertDialog Dialog = ValidationDialog.create();
                Dialog.show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I also Tried Using `getApplicationContext()` in the Intent, but it doesn't work.

Comment: exo5.this.startAct.....

Comment: i tried it in the setNegativeButton but it doesn't work too

Comment: Please give better info. You have problems at design time or at run time? And which ones?

Comment: sorry , i edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in my project and it's launching the activity.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder ValidationDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(exo5.this);
                ValidationDialog.setTitle("Validation");
                ValidationDialog.setMessage("Voulez-vous vraiment valider").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(exo5.this, MyTestAct.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Non", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog Dialog = ValidationDialog.create();
                Dialog.show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: I literally copied pasted it and it still doesn't work, can't understand why

Comment: I created a new project with the same class and it works now, still don't understand the problem